# NSXMLParser in model class gives me no result

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I have a separate class for parsing XML I am getting from server. Here is my model class :

```
#import "CheckLoginModel.h"
#import "Common.h"
#import "Utils.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation CheckLoginModel
@synthesize strUserID;
@synthesize strUserName;
@synthesize i;
@synthesize dict;

   -(void)CheckLogin:(NSString *)strDeviceToken
{
    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        @try
        {
            NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                                     "<soapenv:Envelope \n"
                                     "xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n"
                                     "xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> \n"
                                     "<soapenv:Header/>\n"
                                     "<soapenv:Body>\n"
                                     "<tem:CheckDeviceToken>\n"
                                     "<tem:dt>%@</tem:dt>\n"
                                     "</tem:CheckDeviceToken>\n"
                                     "</soapenv:Body>\n"
                                     "</soapenv:Envelope>\n",strDeviceToken];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kMainURL]; 
            NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];             
            NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];          
            [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
            [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/CheckDeviceToken" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
            [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
            [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
            if( theConnection )
            {
                webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"The Connection is NULL");
            }
        }@catch (NSException *ex) {
            [Utils LogExceptionOnServer:@"ChatApplicationAppDelegate" methodName:@"CheckLogin" exception:[ex description]];
        }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
    [theXML release];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
    [xmlParser release];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];

    //if(strUserName != NULL)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"register" object:self userInfo:dict];
    //[dict release];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark XML PARSING RELATED FUNCTIONS
#pragma mark -

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"CheckDeviceTokenResult"])
    {

    }

    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a:UserID"])
    {
        if(!soapResults)
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a:UserName"])
    {
        if(!soapResults)
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a:UserID"])
    {
        i = [soapResults intValue];
        strUserID = soapResults;
        soapResults = nil;
        [dict setObject:strUserID forKey:@"id"];
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a:UserName"])
    {
        strUserName = soapResults;
        soapResults = nil;
        [dict setObject:strUserName forKey:@"name"];

    }

}


@end
```

When I debug my application and reach `didEndElement`, soapResult gives me nothing. On the contrary, when I use the same code in my controller class, I get the desired results, I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not implementing parser:foundCharacters: I see that your allocating the string in start element but you would need to get the data out and set soapResults in foundCharacters.  Where do you assign to soapResults?  I don't see any code that ever assigns it which is why it's nil.

Also, didEndElement fires whenever the parser reaches the end of an element - not when it's done parsing.  That would be parserDidEndDocument.  So, it's possible that the parser hit the end of an element but still hasn't passed the two elements your interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Was a silly mistake. Thanks for bringing it out.

Comment: That's fine - sometimes it just takes a different set of eyes.  Can't count the number of times I've called someone over to look at code with fresh set of eyes :)